# Constructor args in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

How will I instantiate a named constructor. The constructor is like this

```
 public MachineInPitImpl(MachineInPitImpl mip){
 //here are the attributes initialised
 }
```

How will I give this constructor as constructor-args in spring.

I have tried this, but not working, it still initializes the default constructor. I dont want to initialize the default cons. I want the spring to initialize the above constructor

```
<bean id="machineInPitImpl" class="minestar.pitlink.domain.pitmodel.MachineInPitImpl" abstract="true">
    <constructor-arg ref="machineInPitImpl"/>

</bean>
```

Comment: So, you want to initialize a bean with itself? That doesn't make any sense. Why don't you use Java config, which would allow defining your beans in Java, rather than XML?

Comment: @JBNizet There are two constructors in that class. But I need this constructor to be initialized when the class loads not the default one. Can I achieve this?

Comment: This is a part of 13 GB code. I am making some amendments in that.

Comment: "when the class loads not the default one" What do you mean?

Comment: @Tichodroma The full sentence is "I need this constructor to be initialized when the class loads not the default one" . I need spring to initialize the above constructor not the default constructor.

Comment: And what should be the value of the argument? You can't construct a bean with itself as argument as you're doing. `Foo foo = new Foo(foo);` doesn't make sense. That's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @nos The solution that you wrote earlier in answer, will that work?

Comment: @JBNizet Well thats the requirement. MachineInPitImpl is an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Spring injects dependencies so that you don't have to pass objects around just to be used as constructor arguments.

define whatever references you need as members that will be injected by spring automatically, and call an init method to perform whatever logic you want upon instantiation.

```
<bean id="machineInPitImpl" class="minestar.pitlink.domain.pitmodel.MachineInPitImpl"  abstract="true"  
  init-method="init"
  p:machineInPitImpl-ref="machineInPitImpl"  
/>
```

note that i'm ignoring you're attempting to inject a bean onto itself which doesn't make much sense as pointed out by commenters.

Comment: I don't see this as an improvement though.  There's nothing wrong with using proper constructors, even when using Spring.  The only reason his code doesn't work is that he is injecting the bean into itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to inject the same bean reference in the xml,

```
       <bean id="textEditor" class="com.tutorialspoint.TextEditor">
          <constructor-arg ref="spellChecker"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="spellChecker" class="com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker">
       </bean>


       public TextEditor(SpellChecker spellChecker) {
          System.out.println("Inside TextEditor constructor." );
          this.spellChecker = spellChecker;
       }



       public SpellChecker(){
      System.out.println("Inside SpellChecker constructor." );
       }
```

Makes the sense.when you try to do so,

```
ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app.xml");

      TextEditor te = (TextEditor) context.getBean("textEditor");
```